# PHP/SQL login form having problems

Tags: php, sql, forms, authentication

I'm trying to use the following form to log in, but it always jump to invalid username. Am I missing anything in here?

**Database Connection:**

```
$link   =   mysqli_connect("localhost","X","X","X");

if($link == false) {
    die("Error" .mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

**Login Script:**

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>
<!-- The HTML login form -->
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<?php
} else {
    // Include database credentials
    include('../db_connect.php');
    $mysqli =   new mysqli($link);
    // check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    $username   =   $_POST['username'];
    $password   =   $_POST['password'];

    $sql        =   "SELECT * from admin WHERE admin_email LIKE '{$username}' AND admin_password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $result     =   $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
        echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Logged in successfully</p>";
        // do stuffs
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you save plain password into database????Or it is md5 or hash??

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think getting rid of the `{}` around the `$username` and `$password` should fix the issue, and yea, using `LIKE` is bad. I could then type %abijeet% in my username field

Comment: Is that because `$result->num_rows == 0`? Try `var_dump($result->fetch_all());` to see what is actually coming out of the query.

Comment: @AbijeetPatro Even better: *username* = `%` and *password* = `%` suffices.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think getting rid of the `{}` around the `$username` and `$password` should fix the issue, and yea, using LIKE for login is bad. I could then type **%abijeet%** in my username and **%p%** in the password field and get logged in as long as there is someone called abijeet in the system and has a password with the letter p in it.

**Using PDO**

Also, filtering the input from the $_POST is a good idea. In general, I'd ask you to drop using mysqli and look into PDO - http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Using PDO properly with parameters will secure you against SQL Injection attacks.

**Hashing the password**

Don't store the password in plain test, hash it before saving. Check here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

**UPDATE** -

OK, so as pointed out the `{}` are ok. Another thing that looks suspicious to me is the condition checking.

I would change it to this -

```
// Check the condition checking below!
if ($result->num_rows !== 1) {
    echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>Logged in successfully</p>";
    // do stuffs
}
```

It could be an operator precedence issue and is anyways more confusing.

Comment: The `"{$var}"` syntax is okay inside double-quoted strings.